# how to transform a ZOD Discriminate Union to Enum

Tags: typescript, zod

I have the following code

```
const DE = z.object({ kind: z.literal("DE"), value: z.literal("EUR") })
const AT = z.object({ kind: z.literal("AT"), value: z.literal("EUR") })
const CH = z.object({ kind: z.literal("CH"), value: z.literal("CHF") })

const countries = z.union([DE, AT, CH])
```

I want to create a function that extracts the `kind`s and creates an (Zod) enum out of this.

```
const countryEnums = extractKindsToEnum(countries)

//should yield
//const countryEnums = z.enum(["DE", "AT", "CH"])
//and the following should be true too
type TCountryEnum = z.infer<typeof countryEnums>
//yields
type TCountryEnum = "DE" | "AT" | "CH"
```

Answer (score 2):

It tough to create a function to deal generically with tuples of various sizes. There may be some way to pull this off with TypeScript and Zod and perhaps if I come across it then I'll share what I come up with but in the meantime maybe the following alternative approaches will suffice in your scenario or help others.

#### A. Create a one off `ZodEnum` schema:

```js
const countryEnums= z.enum([
    countries.options.map((country) => country.shape.kind.value)[0],
    ...countries.options.map((country) => country.shape.kind.value).slice(1),
] as const);
```

#### B. Invert the dependency by creating the enum first and then basing the individual union options based off the enum values:

```js
const countryEnums = z.enum(["DE", "AT", "CH"]);

const DE = z.object({ kind: z.literal(countryEnums.Enum.DE), value: z.literal("EUR") });
const AT = z.object({ kind: z.literal(countryEnums.Enum.AT), value: z.literal("EUR") });
const CH = z.object({ kind: z.literal(countryEnums.Enum.CH), value: z.literal("CHF") });

const countries = z.union([DE, AT, CH]);
```